# Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

Tags: ros, catkin, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi... I am to ROS and i would be posting lots of questions. :)
Th thing i am trying to  do is that i want to create multiple packages inside single catkin workspace.
I created my package "my_first_pkg" inside "catkin_ws/src". It worked fine. Then i tried to add another package in the same "catkin_ws/src" with the name "my_second_pkg" using "catkin_create_pkg".  Then i run following command

catkin_make

it gives me following error.
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240081/invoking-%22make-cmake_check_build_system%22-failed/) by [UsmanArif](https://answers.ros.org/users/27566/usmanarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-07-21**:
It sounds like there is more than just one line in this error message; please **edit** your question to include the full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
Thanks for the reply. I found the error. There was problem with the other packages in the same workspace. One of the other package had wrong cmakelist.txt file..

Thanks :)

---

Originally posted by [UsmanArif](https://answers.ros.org/users/27566/usmanarif/) with karma: 41 on 2016-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0